# jQuery hover event toggle class not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been debugging this issue for a good while now and I am so confused to why this isn't working.

As you can see I am running the following code on JSFiddle and it seems to work without any issues at all:

```js
  $(".assistance-submit-btn").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass("assistance-submit-btn-mouseover");
  });
```

```css
.assistance-submit-btn {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight:300;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  color: #333;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  display: block;
}

.assistance-submit-btn-mouseover {
  transform:translate(10px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="assistance-submit-btn" value="Submit">Submit&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
```

As you can see when the `assistance-submit-btn` element is hovered it will add a class to the `i` element.

This code is a direct copy from my local website that I am developing however for some reason on my local system it will not execute when the `assistance-submit-btn` element is hovered.

So far I have tried adding a CSS hover to the element itself just to see whether or not the element was behind another element and unable to hover.

The only difference that I can think of on my local setup is that the `assistance-submit-btn` element is pulled in by AJAX. Could this effect the jQuery hover event? Any suggestions to why this might be happening would be much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE: Forgot to mention I am getting no errors within my console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's because of Ajax dynamic content. Use this code:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).children('i').addClass("assistance-submit-btn-mouseover");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
         $(this).children('i').removeClass("assistance-submit-btn-mouseover");
    }
});
```

Comment: you cannot delegate pseudo event `hover`. You have to delegate `mouseenter/mouseleave` events: `$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.assistance-submit-btn', function () {})`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I have tried this and it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: @NickMaddren See my comment above

Comment: @Justinas Correct but would be more compact: `$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.assistance-submit-btn', function(e) {
 $(this).children('i').toggleClass("assistance-submit-btn-mouseover");
})`

Comment: Yes that worked thanks for the help! So because AJAX is dynamic does any event tied to an element that was pulled in by AJAX need $(document).on added to it every time? If so why is this? Once again thanks.

Comment: @NickMaddren Because when you do `$(selector).event()` you bind to already existing element. New elements will not have this. While `$(staticElement).on(event, dynamicElement)` will bind to any future elements including current elements.

Comment: @NickMaddren Ajax or not, the thing is you have to bind event once element is available in DOM. If you bind it before, no event is bound because the matched set return empty object or dynamic element is not included in matched set. You can delegate to any ancestor level which is static, meaning present in DOM at time you bind event. See as a [good read](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Right okay I now understand, thank you both for your help.